# How to sort list of list by size of list and by element in list in mixed list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list

```
list = [1, 2, 3, [3, [1, 2]]]
```

the result would be:

```
[[[2, 1], 3], 3, 2, 1]
```

How to sort that list by size of list and by element?

Comment: It's not issue please share what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to *recursively* sort the list:

```
def recursive_sort(item):
  if isinstance(item, list):
      item[:] = sorted(item, key=recursive_sort)
      return 0, -len(item)
  else:
      return 1, -item

lst = [1, 2, 3, [3, [1, 2], [2, 3, 6]]]      
print(sorted(lst, key=recursive_sort))
# [[[6, 3, 2], [2, 1], 3], 3, 2, 1]
```

**Caveat**: This is more of an academic exercise and should never be used in production code. The state of the list during a sort (at least with Timsort in CPython) is **undefined**, so you shouldn't count on this to always work.